# java.lang.IllegalStateException: missing behavior definition for the preceding method call getMessage("title")

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng, easymock

I'm using EasyMock(version 2.4) and TestNG for writing UnitTest.

I have a following scenario and I cannot change the way class hierarchy is defined.

I'm testing ClassB which is extending ClassA.

**ClassB look like this**

```
public class ClassB extends ClassA  {

  public ClassB()
    {
        super("title");
    }

    @Override
    public String getDisplayName() 
    {
        return ClientMessages.getMessages("ClassB.title");
    }

}
```

**ClassA code**

```
public abstract class ClassA {
    private String title;

    public ClassA(String title)
    {
        this.title = ClientMessages.getMessages(title);
    }

    public String getDisplayName()
    {
        return this.title;
    }
}
```

**ClientMessages class code**

```
public class ClientMessages {
    private static MessageResourse messageResourse;

    public ClientMessages(MessageResourse messageResourse) 
    {
        this.messageResourse = messageResourse;
    }
    public static String getMessages(String code) 
    {
        return messageResourse.getMessage(code);

    }
}
```

**MessageResourse Class code**

```
public class MessageResourse {
    public String getMessage(String code) 
    {
        return code;
    }
}
```

**Testing ClassB**

```
import static org.easymock.classextension.EasyMock.createMock;

import org.easymock.classextension.EasyMock;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class ClassBTest
{
    private MessageResourse mockMessageResourse = createMock(MessageResourse.class);
    private ClassB classToTest;
    private ClientMessages clientMessages;


    @Test
    public void testGetDisplayName()
    {

    EasyMock.expect(mockMessageResourse.getMessage("ClassB.title")).andReturn("someTitle");

        clientMessages = new ClientMessages(mockMessageResourse);

        classToTest = new ClassB();

        Assert.assertEquals("someTitle" , classToTest.getDisplayName());
        EasyMock.replay(mockMessageResourse);
    }
}
```

When I'm running this this test I'm getting  following exception:

***java.lang.IllegalStateException: missing behavior definition for the preceding method call getMessage("title")***

While debugging what I found is, it's not considering the mock method call
***mockMessageResourse.getMessage("ClassB.title")*** as it has been called from the construtor (ClassB object creation).

Can any one please help me how to test in this case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 49):

You need to call `EasyMock.replay(mock)` before calling the method under test. After calling the method under test you can call `EasyMock.verify(mock)` to verify the mock is called.

Next you need to add another `expect` call with the "title" argument since you call it twice.

Code:

```
EasyMock.expect(mockMessageResourse.getMessage("title")).andReturn("title");    
EasyMock.expect(mockMessageResourse.getMessage("ClassB.title")).andReturn("someTitle");
EasyMock.replay(mockMessageResourse);
clientMessages = new ClientMessages(mockMessageResourse);

classToTest = new ClassB();

Assert.assertEquals("someTitle" , classToTest.getDisplayName());
EasyMock.verify(mockMessageResourse);
```

Answer (score 24):

In my case, it was caused by the omission of a return value specification (andReturn(...)).
http://www.smcmaster.com/2011/04/easymock-issue-1-missing-behavior.html for more details.

Comment: Same here. Checking if methods return something even when you don't expect it (method chaining) seems a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

This can have various causes (`someMock` is the name of your mocked Object in this answer).
On the one side it can be that you need to expect the call via

```
expect(someMock.someMethod(anyObject()).andReturn("some-object");
```

like in [Reda's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16274764/1578508).
It can also be that you forgot to call `replay(someMock)` before you used the mock, like you can see in [Julien Rentrop's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3005154/1578508).

A last thing that is possible that wasn't mentioned here is that you used the mock somewhere else before in a test and forgot to reset the mock via `reset(someMock)`.

This can happen if you have multiple Unit Tests like this:

```
private Object a = EasyMock.createMock(Object.class);

@Test
public void testA() throws Exception {
   expect(a.someThing()).andReturn("hello");
   replay(a);

   // some test code and assertions etc. here
   verify(a);
}

@Test
public void testB() throws Exception {
   expect(a.someThing()).andReturn("hello");
   replay(a);

   // some test code and assertions etc. here
   verify(a);
}
```

This will fail on one test with the IllegalStateException, because the mock a was not reset before being used in the next test. To solve it you can do the following:

```
private Object a = EasyMock.createMock(Object.class);

@Test
public void testA() throws Exception {
   expect(a.someThing()).andReturn("hello");
   replay(a);

   // some test code and assertions etc. here
   verify(a);
}

@Test
public void testB() throws Exception {
   expect(a.someThing()).andReturn("hello");
   replay(a);

   // some test code and assertions etc. here
   verify(a);
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
   reset(a); // reset the mock after each test
}
```

Comment: missing `reset()` was my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should put your call to `replay` after the `expect` calls, and *before* you use your mock. In this case you should change your test to something like this:

```
@Test
public void testGetDisplayName()
{ 

    EasyMock.expect(mockMessageResourse.getMessage("ClassB.title")).andReturn("someTitle");
    EasyMock.replay(mockMessageResourse);

    clientMessages = new ClientMessages(mockMessageResourse);

    classToTest = new ClassB();

    Assert.assertEquals("someTitle" , classToTest.getDisplayName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, this exception was occurring because the method I was trying to stub was `final` (something I hadn't realized).

If you want to stub a `final` method you'll need to use [Powermock](https://github.com/powermock/powermock).