# java.lang.IllegalStateException: missing behavior definition for the preceding method call getLast(...)

Tags: java, easymock

I've already read similar questions on SO like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004184/java-lang-illegalstateexception-missing-behavior-definition-for-the-preceding-m), but I can't solve my problem.
I've modified an existing class and when I try to build it with ant I get the following unit test failed error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: missing behavior definition for the preceding method call getLast(class mypackage.model.MyObj, 1)
>       at org.easymock.internal.MockInvocationHandler.invoke(MockInvocationHandler.java:43)
>       at org.easymock.internal.ObjectMethodsFilter.invoke(ObjectMethodsFilter.java:73)
>       at org.easymock.internal.ClassProxyFactory$MockMethodInterceptor.intercept(ClassProxyFactory.java:92)
>       at mypackage.service.MyService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$347f5838.getLast()
>       at mypackage.controller.MyController.myControllerMethod(MyController.java:265)
>       at mypackage.controller.MyController.myControllerMethodTest(MyControllerTest.java:207)

In `MyController.java` I've added a piece of code like (the error is at line 265):

```
263. public void myControllerMethod(Integer id) {
264.   String myString = null;
265.   MyObj myObj = (MyObj) myService.getLast(MyObj.class, id);
266.   try {
267.     myString = myObj.getMyProp().getMyObj();
268.   } catch (Exception e) {
269.     myString = "";
270.   }
```

`MyControllerTest.java` simply calls `myControllerMethod`, like:

```
207. myController.myControllerMethod(1);
```

I've already tried to add an "expectation" before the line 207, like:

```
206. EasyMock.expect(myServiceMock.getLast(MyObj.class, 1));
```

rather than:

```
206. EasyMock.expect(myServiceMock.getLast(MyObj.class, 1)).andReturn(new MyObj());
```

But to no avail.
Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I solved with `EasyMock.replay(myServiceMock)` as I found in [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/easymock/easymock_example_with_replay.htm) example.

That's a kind of "activation" of the expectation inserted before.

Comment: Yes. First you record everything you need. Then you go in replay mode. You can see that as a BDD "Given" (replay) "When" (call to the mock) "Then" (verify).